# OPC Protocol and PLC Interworking

Tags: opc

Hi I am studying IoT with PLC.

I was looking for a way to poll data from PLC modules, and found OPC Protocol that seems to be the standard.

If I adopt this protocol and make a server that polls data via OPC and mediate that protocol, will I be able to connect to any kinds of PLC?

I saw some solutions and they highlight specific vendor-drivers.

Does this mean OPC is not a standard and I need to see each vendor's protocols?

I need some grasp on this, so please advice on how I should communicate with PLCs with JAVA Server

Answer (score 0):

OPC has multiple different versions.

The major ones you might consider are:

- OPC DA ("Data Access"), which is based on Microsoft OLE, COM and uses DCOM as a wire protocol.
- OPC UA ("Unified Architecture"), which has a more complex data model and has a distinct protocol specification. There are multiple wire protocols, including an XML based protocol and a compact binary encoded protocol. There are different types of security choices; interoperability means matching everything up.

For PLC access it may be that you are using a gateway between a wire protocol (for example Modbus or a vendor protocol) and an OPC programming environment. In this case you do not need to be aware of the protocol implementation; the driver/gateway is responsible for the conversion into the OPC programming environment.

In a Java environment you could find an OPC UA supplier that provides a Java API and has driver support for the devices you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so only relatively recently did PLCs start to communicate via OPC-UA natively. Typically, each vendor has their own sometimes open, sometimes proprietary protocol that you need to use to talk to the PLC.

The traditional role of a OPC servers has been to let the vendor of the server worry about all the protocol details for each kind of device while clients just need to know OPC-DA or OPC-UA, which is an open standard.